# ZF2 - How to Listen for Events and Trigger a Service because of it?

Tags: php, event-handling, zend-framework2

Have been trying to learn how to implement Services because they get Triggered by a Listener. [Have](https://framework.zend.com/manual/2.4/en/in-depth-guide/services-and-servicemanager.html) [been](https://framework.zend.com/manual/2.4/en/modules/zend.event-manager.event-manager.html) [doing](https://samsonasik.wordpress.com/2013/05/18/zend-framework-2-register-event-listeners-in-configuration-file/) [a](http://www.michaelgallego.fr/blog/2013/05/12/understanding-the-zend-framework-2-event-manager/) [serious](https://samsonasik.wordpress.com/2013/03/30/zend-framework-2-getting-closer-with-eventmanager/) [lot](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24897470/listeners-automatically-being-attached-when-using-listeners-config-key) [of](http://resoftsol.com/events-the-eventmanager-and-listeneraggregates-in-zend-framework-2/) [reading](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13978748/zf2-how-to-attach-listener-on-the-event-in-the-module-class) [the](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28524590/zf2-how-to-listen-to-the-dispatch-event-of-a-specific-controller) [last](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30794259/how-to-trigger-an-event-attached-to-the-shared-event-manager-in-zf2) few days to get it to work, but have been finding it difficult. Thus I'm thinking my understanding of the order of things might be flawed.

> **The use case I'm trying to get to work is the following**:
>
> Just before an Address Entity (with Doctrine, but that's not
>   important) gets saved (flushed), a Service must be triggered to check
>   if the Coordinates for the Address are set, and if not, create and
>   fill a new Coordinates Entity and link it to the Address. The
>   Coordinates are to be gotten from Google Maps Geocoding API.

Will show below what and how I'm understanding things in the hope I make myself clear. Will do it in steps to show added code in between and tell you what does and doesn't work, as far as I know.

Now, my understanding of all of the information I've gotten the last few days is this:

A Listener has to be registered with ZF2's ServiceManager. The listener "attaches" certain conditions to the (Shared)EventManager. An EventManager is unique to an object, but the SharedEventManager is 'global' in the application.

In the Address module's `Module.php` class I've added the following function:

```
/**
 * @param EventInterface $e
 */
public function onBootstrap(EventInterface $e)
{
    $eventManager = $e->getTarget()->getEventManager();
    $eventManager->attach(new AddressListener());
}
```

This gets works, the AddressListener gets triggered.

The AddressListener is as follows:

```
use Address\Entity\Address;
use Address\Service\GoogleCoordinatesService;
use Zend\EventManager\EventManagerInterface;
use Zend\EventManager\ListenerAggregateInterface;
use Zend\Stdlib\CallbackHandler;

class AddressListener implements ListenerAggregateInterface
{
    /**
     * @var CallbackHandler
     */
    protected $listeners;

    /**
     * @param EventManagerInterface $events
     */
    public function attach(EventManagerInterface $events)
    {
        $sharedEvents = $events->getSharedManager();

        // Not sure how and what order params should be. The ListenerAggregateInterface docblocks didn't help me a lot with that either, as did the official ZF2 docs. So, been trying a few things...

        $this->listeners[] = $sharedEvents->attach(GoogleCoordinatesService::class, 'getCoordinates', [$this, 'addressCreated'], 100);

        $this->listeners[] = $sharedEvents->attach(Address::class, 'entity.preFlush', [GoogleCoordinatesService::class, 'getCoordinates'], 100);
    }

    /**
     * @param EventManagerInterface $events
     */
    public function detach(EventManagerInterface $events)
    {
        foreach ($this->listeners as $index => $listener) {
            if ($events->detach($listener)) {
                unset($this->listeners[$index]);
            }
        }
    }

    public function addressCreated()
    {
        $foo = 'bar'; // This line is here to as debug break. Line is never used...
    }
}
```

I was expecting a Listener to work as a sort-of stepping stone point to where things get triggered, based on the `->attach()` functions in the `function attach(...){}`. However, this does not seem to work, as nothing gets triggered. Not the `addressCreated()` function and not the `getCoordinates` function in the `GoogleCoordinatesService`.

The code above is supposed to trigger the `GoogleCoordinatesService` function `getCoordinates`. The Service has a few requirements though, such as the presence of the EntityManager of Doctrine, the Address Entity it concerns and configuration.

To that effect, I've created the following configuration.

File `google.config.php` (gets loaded, checked that)

```
return [
    'google' => [
        'services' => [
            'maps' => [
                'services' => [
                    'geocoding' => [
                        'api_url' => 'https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/geocode/json?',
                        'api_key' => '',
                        'url_params' => [
                            'required' => [
                                'address',
                            ],
                            'optional' => [
                                'key'
                            ],
                        ],
                    ],
                ],
            ],
        ],
    ],
];
```

And in `module.config.php` I've registered the Service with a Factory

```
'service_manager' => [
    'factories' => [
        GoogleCoordinatesService::class => GoogleCoordinatesServiceFactory::class,
    ],
],
```

The Factory is pretty standard ZF2 stuff, but to paint a complete picture, here is the `GoogleCoordinatesServiceFactory.php` class. (Removed comments/typehints/etc)

```
class GoogleCoordinatesServiceFactory implements FactoryInterface
{
    public function createService(ServiceLocatorInterface $serviceLocator, $options = [])
    {
        $serviceManager = $serviceLocator->getServiceLocator();
        $entityManager = $serviceManager->get(EntityManager::class);
        $config = $serviceManager->get('Config');

        if (isset($options) && isset($options['address'])) {
            $address = $options['address'];
        } else {
            throw new InvalidArgumentException('Must provide an Address Entity.');
        }

        return new GoogleCoordinatesService(
            $entityManager,
            $config,
            $address
        );
    }
}
```

Below is the `GoogleCoordinatesService` class. However, nothing ever gets triggered to executed in there. As it doesn't even gets called I'm sure the problem lies in the code above, but cannot find out why. From what I've read and tried, I'm expecting that the class itself should get called, via the Factory and the `getCoordinates` function should be triggered.

So, the class. I've removed a bunch of standard getters/setters, comments, docblocks and typehints to make it shorter.

```
class GoogleCoordinatesService implements EventManagerAwareInterface
{
    protected $eventManager;
    protected $entityManager;
    protected $config;
    protected $address;

    /**
     * GoogleCoordinatesServices constructor.
     * @param EntityManager $entityManager
     * @param Config|array $config
     * @param Address $address
     * @throws InvalidParamNameException
     */
    public function __construct(EntityManager $entityManager, $config, Address $address)
    {    
        $this->config = $config;
        $this->address = $address;
        $this->entityManager = $entityManager;
    }

    public function getCoordinates()
    {
        $url = $this->getConfig()['api_url'] . 'address=' . $this->urlFormatAddress($this->getAddress());

        $response = json_decode(file_get_contents($url), true);

        if ($response['status'] == 'OK') {
            $coordinates = new Coordinates();
            $coordinates
                ->setLatitude($response['results'][0]['geometry']['location']['lat'])
                ->setLongitude($response['results'][0]['geometry']['location']['lng']);

            $this->getEntityManager()->persist($coordinates);

            $this->getAddress()->setCoordinates($coordinates);
            $this->getEntityManager()->persist($this->getAddress());

            $this->getEntityManager()->flush();

            $this->getEventManager()->trigger(
                'addressReceivedCoordinates',
                null,
                ['address' => $this->getAddress()]
            );
        } else {
            // TODO throw/set error/status
        }
    }

    public function urlFormatAddress(Address $address)
    {
        $string = // format the address into a string

        return urlencode($string);
    }

    public function getEventManager()
    {
        if ($this->eventManager === null) {
            $this->setEventManager(new EventManager());
        }

        return $this->eventManager;
    }

    public function setEventManager(EventManagerInterface $eventManager)
    {
        $eventManager->addIdentifiers([
            __CLASS__,
            get_called_class()
        ]);

        $this->eventManager = $eventManager;
        return $this;
    }

    // Getters/Setters for EntityManager, Config and Address
}
```

So, that's the setup to handle it when a certain event gets triggered. Now it should, of course, get triggered. For this use case I've setup a trigger in the `AbstractActionController` of my own (extends ZF2's `AbstractActionController`). Doing that like so:

```
if ($form->isValid()) {
    $entity = $form->getObject();
    $this->getEntityManager()->persist($entity);

    try {
        // Trigger preFlush event, pass along Entity. Other Listeners can subscribe to this name.
        $this->getEventManager()->trigger(
            'entity.preFlush',
            null,
            [get_class($entity) => $entity] // key = "Address\Entity\Address" for use case
        );

        $this->getEntityManager()->flush();
    } catch (\Exception $e) {
        // Error thrown
    }
    // Success stuff, like a trigger "entity.postFlush"
}
```

So yea. At the moment at a bit of a loss on how to get it working.

Any help would be very much appreciated and would love explanations as to the "why" of it is that a solution works. That would really help me out making more of these services :)

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Been at it for a while, but have managed to figure out why it was not working. I was attaching `Listener`s to `EventManager`s, but should have been attaching them to the `SharedEventManager`. This is because I have the triggers (in this instance) in the `AbstractActionController`, thus they all create their own `EventManager` (as they're unique) when instantiated.

Has been a tough few days wrapping my head around it all, but [this article](https://www.masterzendframework.com/tutorial/zend-framework-2-event-manager-a-gentle-introduction/) helped me out most, or perhaps it just made things click with my original research in the question and subsequent trial & error + debugging.

Below the code as it is now, in working order. I'll try to explain along as the code comes as to how I understand that it works. If I get it wrong at some point I hope someone corrects me.

---

First up, we need a `Listener`, a class which registers components and events to "listen" for them to trigger. (They listen for certain (named) objects to trigger certain events)

The realization quickly came that pretty much every Listener would need the `$listeners = [];` and the `detach(EventManagerInterface $events){...}` function. So I created an `AbstractListener` class.

```
namespace Mvc\Listener;

use Zend\EventManager\EventManagerInterface;
use Zend\EventManager\ListenerAggregateInterface;

/**
 * Class AbstractListener
 * @package Mvc\Listener
 */
abstract class AbstractListener implements ListenerAggregateInterface
{
    /**
     * @var array
     */
    protected $listeners = [];

    /**
     * @param EventManagerInterface $events
     */
    public function detach(EventManagerInterface $events)
    {
        foreach ($this->listeners as $index => $listener) {
            if ($events->detach($listener)) {
                unset($this->listeners[$index]);
            }
        }
    }
}
```

After the above mentioned realization about having to use the `SharedEventManager` and with the `AbstractListener` created, the `AddressListener` class has ended up like so.

```
namespace Address\Listener;

use Address\Event\AddressEvent;
use Admin\Address\Controller\AddressController;
use Mvc\Listener\AbstractListener;
use Zend\EventManager\EventManagerInterface;

/**
 * Class AddressListener
 * @package Address\Listener
 */
class AddressListener extends AbstractListener
{
    /**
     * @param EventManagerInterface $events
     */
    public function attach(EventManagerInterface $events)
    {
        $sharedManager = $events->getSharedManager();
        $sharedManager->attach(AddressController::class, 'entity.postPersist', [new AddressEvent(), 'addCoordinatesToAddress']);
    }
}
```

The main difference with attaching events to `EventManager` versus the `SharedEventManager` is that the latter listens for a specific class to emit a trigger. In this instance it will listen for the `AddressController::class` to emit the trigger `entity.postPersist`. Upon "hearing" that it's triggered it will call a callback function. In this case that is registered with this array parameter: `[new AddressEvent(), 'addCoordinatesToAddress']`, meaning that it will use the class `AddressEvent` and the function `addCoordinatesToAddress`.

To test if this works, and if you're working along with this answer, you can create the trigger in your own Controller. I've been working in the `addAction` of the `AbstractActionController`, which gets called by the `addAction` of the `AddressController`. Below the trigger for the Listener above:

```
if ($form->isValid()) {
    $entity = $form->getObject();

    $this->getEntityManager()->persist($entity);

    $this->getEventManager()->trigger(
        'entity.postPersist',
        $this,
        [get_class($entity) => $entity]
    );

    try {
        $this->getEntityManager()->flush();
    } catch (\Exception $e) {
        // Error stuff
    }
    // Remainder of function
}
```

The `->trigger()` function in the above code shows the usage of the following parameters:

- 'entity.postPersist' - This is the event name
- $this - This is the "component" or object the event is called for. In this instance it will be `Address\Controller\AddressController`
- [get_class($entity) => $entity] - These are parameters to send along with this `Event` object. It will cause you to have available `$event->getParams()[Address::class]` which will have the `$entity` value.

The first two parameters will trigger the Listener in the `SharedEventManager`. To test if it all works, it's possible to modify the Listener's attach function.

Modify it to this and create a function within the the Listener so you can see it working:

```
public function attach(EventManagerInterface $events)
{
    $sharedManager = $events->getSharedManager();
    $sharedManager->attach(AddressController::class, 'entity.postPersist', [$this, 'test']);
}

public function test(Event $event)
{
    var_dump($event);
    exit;
}
```

Lastly, to make sure that the above actually works, the Listener must be registered with the `EventManager`. This happens in the `onBootstrap` function in the `Module.php` file of the module (Address in this case). Register like below.

```
public function onBootstrap(MvcEvent $e)
{
    $eventManager = $e->getApplication()->getEventManager();
    $eventManager->attach(new AddressListener());
}
```

If you debug the code of the `addAction` in the `AbstractActionController`, see it pass the trigger and next you're in the `test` function, then your Listener works.

The above code also implies that the `AddressListener` class can be used to attach more than one listener. So you could also register stuff for `entity.prePersist`, `entity.preFlush`, `entity.postFlush` and anything else you can think of.

Next up, revert the Listener back to what it was at the beginning (revert the `attach` function and remove the `test` function).

I also noticed that pretty much every `Event` handling class would need to be able to set and get the `EventManager`. Thus, for this I've created an `AbstractEvent` class, like below.

```
namespace Mvc\Event;

use Zend\EventManager\EventManager;
use Zend\EventManager\EventManagerAwareInterface;
use Zend\EventManager\EventManagerInterface;

abstract class AbstractEvent implements EventManagerAwareInterface
{
    /**
     * @var EventManagerInterface
     */
    protected $events;

    /**
     * @param EventManagerInterface $events
     */
    public function setEventManager(EventManagerInterface $events)
    {
        $events->setIdentifiers([
            __CLASS__,
            get_class($this)
        ]);

        $this->events = $events;
    }

    /**
     * @return EventManagerInterface
     */
    public function getEventManager()
    {
        if (!$this->events) {
            $this->setEventManager(new EventManager());
        }

        return $this->events;
    }
}
```

To be honest, I'm not quite sure why we set 2 identifiers in the `setEventManager` function. But suffice to say that it's used to register callbacks for Events. (this could use more/detailed explanation if someone feels so inclined as to provide it)

In the `AddressListener` we're trying to call the `addCoordinatesToAddress` function of the `AddressEvent` class. So we're going to have to create that, I did it like below.

```
namespace Address\Event;

use Address\Entity\Address;
use Address\Service\GoogleGeocodingService;
use Country\Entity\Coordinates;
use Mvc\Event\AbstractEvent;
use Zend\EventManager\Event;
use Zend\EventManager\Exception\InvalidArgumentException;

class AddressEvent extends AbstractEvent
{
    public function addCoordinatesToAddress(Event $event)
    {
        $params = $event->getParams();
        if (!isset($params[Address::class]) || !$params[Address::class] instanceof Address) {

            throw new InvalidArgumentException(__CLASS__ . ' was expecting param with key ' . Address::class . ' and value instance of same Entity.');
        }

        /** @var Address $address */
        $address = $params[Address::class];

        if (!$address->getCoordinates() instanceof Coordinates) {
            /** @var GoogleGeocodingService $geocodingService */
            $geocodingService = $event->getTarget()->getEvent()->getApplication()->getServiceManager()->get(GoogleGeocodingService::class);
            $geocodingService->addCoordinatesToAddress($address);
        }

        $params = compact('address');
        $this->getEventManager()->trigger(__FUNCTION__, $this, $params);
    }
}
```

In the above you can see that first we check if the parameter we expect has been passed along with the `Event $event` parameter. We know what we should expect and what name the key should have, so we check explicitly.

Next we check if the received `Address` Entity object already has a `Coordinates` object associated with it, if it doesn't, we call a Service to make it happen.

After the `if()` statement has run, we fire another `trigger`. We pass along this `Event` object and the parameters. This last step is not required, but can be handy if you wish to chain events.

---

In the question I mentioned a use case. The above code enables the `Service` (`GoogleGeocodingService`) to get passed the it's requirements and combined with the configuration for the Factory, it gets created via Zend Magic with the `ServiceManager`.

The code to add a new `Coordinates` object to the existing `Address` object was not modified, so I won't make it part of the answer, you can find that in the question.